# Symbol definition in parallel kernels

Tags: parallelization

Suppose I have a reasonably large number of floating point arrays, obtained from prior numerical simulations. These are stored as binary files named `data_#####.dat` where `#####` is the number used as input parameter to my simulation. The files need to be post-processed to obtain some physical data, say area and mass. I currently have a notebook to each file which, schematically, does the following

```
processFile[x_] := Block[{ ...some local variables... },
    importedData = Import[
        "data_"<>ToString[x]<>".dat",
        "Real64", ByteOrdering -> 1, "HeaderBytes" -> 8];

    data[x]["area"] = calculateArea[importedData];
    data[x]["mass"] = calculateMass[importedData];

    x
];

xList = processFile /@ Table[i, {i, 1, 100}];
```

This works pretty well: after the evaluation terminates I can just query things like `data[30]["mass"]` to get the mass of the `n = 30` solution, or `data[87]["area"]` to query the area of the `n = 87` solution. I can even `DumpSave["processed.mx", data]` for later usage.

Note that, in this process, `Definition[data]` contains definitions only for `data[x]["mass"]` and `data[x]["area"]`, and **not** `data[x]`.

The issue is that the actual notebook calculates not just two, but rather around ten physical quantities, per file, and each calculation takes a nontrivial amount of time. It is therefore desirable to parallelize this process.

The obvious thing to do is the change the last line to

```
xList = ParallelMap[processFile, Table[i, {i, 1, 100}]];
```

but, since the results are "stored" as definitions in the `data` symbol, we must first declare it as a *shared function*

```
SetSharedFunction[data]
```

However, this does *not* work.

While `SetSharedFunction` would allow me to do assignments like `data[x] = someValue` in each parallel subkernel (indeed this is what the example does in the documentation), `data[x]["mass"] = someValue` fails because the subkernel first evaluates `data[x]` to `Null`, and obviously Mathematica protests at my attempt to assign a value to `Null["mass"]`.

Is there a way for me to do what I want to do here?

Comment: Why don't you just use a data structure that can be passed around freely (`Association`?) instead of attaching everything to a hard-coded name like `data`?

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for before going with the "attching to `data`" route. Honestly, in my years of using mma I've somehow never come across this rather fundamental built-in. I did try searching for "HashMap in Mathematica" or some such earlier but somehow that yielded nothing useful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, `Association` is clearly an appropriate solution here which I will indeed use. However, the question still holds: is there a way to define to a symbol in the way described above from parallel kernels?

Comment: `Association` is new in version 10.  You can use a workaround similar to `SetSharedFunction[f]; f[prop_, x_] := data[prop][x] = x`, but do not use `SetSharedFunction` on `data` in this case.  `SubValues` don't seem to be supported by `SetSharedFunction`.